# Python Tkinter runtime variable geometry

Tags: python, tkinter

**My Question:**
In the python Tkinter module, is it possible to increase and adjust the size of GUI geometry at runtime to accommodate the number of widgets displayed?

**My case:**
At initialization, I have defined a standard geometry of XxY dimensions. As the program runs, the number of widgets displayed on the GUI increase/decrease. Is there a mechanism to auto adjust the geometry, instead of manually dragging and extending using the borders.

Below I have added two images, Image 1- defined geometry when the program was run. Second Image: During run time, many labels get added and this standard dimensions doesn't show all of them.

[image: GUI not displaying the labels present below the dimension size]

[image: Initial GUI Geometry size]

Comment: I'm actually not sure what you are looking for. Tkinter calculate the width and height of your windows and frames automatically by the space it needs to contain the widgets. Alternatively there are several options e.g. `wm_geometry`, `wm_minsize`, `wm_maxsize`. Also there is the possibility of using the `'<Configure>'` binding to bind a function whenever a configuration like resizing occurs. Could you be more specific for me, cause I don't understand what you looking for.

Comment: @Atlas435  I have added images to the question.. In second image, there are many more numbers (labels) present but not all are being displayed, I am looking for gui to auto adjust to accomodate all of them

Comment: hope you will find an answer that fits to you below.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the [docs](http://www.eso.org/projects/vlt/sw-dev/tcl8.4.19/html/TkCmd/wm.htm#M47) to answer your Question:

> **By default a top-level window appears on the screen in its natural
> size, which is the one determined internally by its widgets and
> geometry managers**. If the natural size of a top-level window changes,
> then the window's size changes to match. A top-level window can be
> given a size other than its natural size in two ways. First, the user
> can resize the window manually using the facilities of the window
> manager, such as resize handles. *Second, the application can request a
> particular size for a top-level window using the wm geometry command*.
> These two cases are handled identically by Tk; in either case, the
> requested size overrides the natural size. **You can return the window
> to its natural by invoking wm geometry with an empty geometry string**.

The problem is that you still want to use your `wm_geometry`, right?
So you cant just put the empty string in the wm_geometry, since this would undo your geometry that you defined before. This would only work if you knew a specific point in your code, e.g. a big widget, that will beyond your defined bounderies.

As I dont know your code I see just this two options:

1. Kepp track of the dimension of widgets you put on your window.
2. Define a minsize of your root window.

**->** You would need to use grid in this case, cause you need the [bbox](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.bbox-method) of the basic widget methods that works with grid, pack return just `(0,0,0,0)`.

So here is the code as exampel:

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

def adder():
    tk.Label(root,text='spacer').grid(column=0,row=_r.get()) #add spacer
    _r.set(_r.get()+1) #next row
    root.update_idletasks() #update_idletasks to get correct value
    if _b.get(): #if this part of the function never happend
        if root.bbox()[3] >= 200: #check if the pixels of your bbox right down corner is beyond the height of 200
            root.geometry('') #go back to natural behavior
            _b.set(False) #set flag that we dont need this part of code anymore
    else:
        pass #skip
        

add_b = tk.Button(root,text='add', command=adder)
add_b.grid(column=0,row=0)

_b = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
_r = tk.IntVar(value=1)


root.mainloop()
```

If you do know, when your frame will beyond your predefined geometry and you just want to span an empty frame then look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63191526/13629335) and call `root.geometry('')` at this point.

The second option is way easier to handle and maybe the preferenced answer.
In this case you just use [wm_minsize](http://www.eso.org/projects/vlt/sw-dev/tcl8.4.19/html/TkCmd/wm.htm#M36) instead of your geometry method:

> The window manager will restrict the window's dimensions to be greater
> than or equal to width and height

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.wm_minsize(width=200,height=200)

def adder():
    tk.Label(root,text='spacer').pack() #add spacer
        

add_b = tk.Button(root,text='add', command=adder)
add_b.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Last but not least you can think about a [scrollable frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/13629335), which should be the best choice since your screen has limits too.

Comment: Thank for you such detailed answer. Appreciate your efforts. I will try the scrollable frame that you have suggested.

Comment: You're welcome, I would appreciate if you accept this answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I will accept answer, as soon as the issue is resolved.